# When two strings are placed in one line of code, they cannot be displayed correctly

Tags: string, listboxitem

Today I am trying to practice using point to point with C#.

In my expectation, when a computer knows the file's  and its IP address through point to point, it will send a request to the target host to transmit resources, and the request contains the required of resources.
When the target host receives the application, it will look up the local storage address of the corresponding file on its own.

```
peername.Equals(listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Split('|')[0])
```

But I found that every time I use equals the result is false.
So I choose to output the two strings to see if they are equal

```
    string peername = e.mess.Split('>')[1];
    MessageBox.Show("!" + peername);
    MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Items[0].ToString().Split('|')[0] + "!");
    string add = peername +"!"+ listBox1.Items[0].ToString().Split('|')[0];
    MessageBox.Show(add);
```

I found that when I show the third message show up, the result is not as expected.
For example, when name is 0.123; the first two result in !0.123 and 0.123!, but the third shows 0.123 instead of the expected 0.123!0.123

I suspect it is the reason that every time I use equals the result is false.
I do not know why it has to be like this. I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Do not tag C for C# questions.

Comment: What is "point to point"?

Comment: In the end this question is about strings. All the information about p2p and requests seems to be irrelevant. But what we need to able to help are the input values and it's really hard to get this information from your question. I'd suggest to a) assign the values to a variable so you can see them, e.g. `var parts = listBox1.Items[0].ToString().Split('|');` then b) use a debugger to understand what happens.